# Make Rake task testable with FactoryGirl user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rake, factory-bot, database-cleaner

I have been trying to test a rake task with RSPEC. So far my understanding of the problem is that DB transactions are creating different contexts for each aspects of the test (one in the test context and one in the rake task execution context). Here are the two files I'm using in my test:

One to make rake tasks available in Rspec and be able to call task.execute:

```
...spec/support/tasks.rb

require "rake"

module TaskExampleGroup
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    let(:task_name) { self.class.top_level_description.sub(/\Arake /, "") }
    let(:tasks) { Rake::Task }
    subject(:task) { tasks[task_name] }
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.define_derived_metadata(:file_path => %r{/spec/tasks/}) do |metadata|
    metadata[:type] = :task
  end
  config.include TaskExampleGroup, type: :task
  config.before(:suite) do
    Rails.application.load_tasks
  end
end
```

One to properly test my rake task:

```
...spec/tasks/reengage_spec.rb

require "rails_helper"

describe "rake reengage:unverified_users", type: :task do

  let(:confirmed_user){create(:user, :confirmed)}

  it "Preloads the Rails environment" do
    expect(task.prerequisites).to include "environment"
  end

  it "Runs gracefully with no users" do
    expect { task.execute }.not_to raise_error
  end

  it "Logs to stdout without errors" do
    expect { task.execute }.to_not output.to_stderr
  end

  it "Reengage confirmed users" do
    task.execute
    expect(confirmed_user).to have_attributes(:reactivated_at => DateTime.now)
  end

end
```

So far, when the rake task is executed through Rspec, it seems like the user I have created is not available in the context of rake, hence his . `reactivated_at` remains nil. I though I could use database cleaner to be able to configure DB transactions and preserve the context but I have no idea where to start.

I could end putting all this code in a lib and test it separately but I'm wondering if there is a way to do this. Is there a straightforward way to share the context of execution or to make my FactoryGirl user available when the task is initialized?

Comment: another way to test a rake task is to move your rake code to a class, that way you can reuse code plus it's easy to test.

Comment: I ended up doing this :) Thank you very much for your answer fanta.